# When EVE is flying, why does her blue trails only appear in space?

Tags: wall-e

Notice that when EVE is flying on Earth and in the Axiom, she doesn't leave blue trails. In space, she leaves blue trails. Why is this so?

Comment: Because a cloud of charged ions will be immediately neutralized in the atmosphere.  Seriously, I'm sure it's a purely artistic decision, because otherwise there are no referents to visualize the acrobatics against.

Comment: She might use a different form of propulsion in space than she does on Earth, too.  Compare, e.g., the Arwings from _Star Fox 64_ .

Comment: @JustinTime-ReinstateMonica - In the commentary, her propulsion on the ground is described as an "anti-gravity" thing. It stands to reason that in space (where there's no gravity) that she's using another form of propulsion.

Comment: There is gravity everywhere.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - There's micro-gravity, sure. My guess is that EVE's anti-grav doesn't work in space as there's *practically nothing* to "push" against